# I want to update my record but It give the exception in cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Users set Username=@Username,Password=@Password,Name=@Name,Address=@Address,Phone=@Phone,@Email=Email,@RoleId=RoleId", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", address.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", phone.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleId", DropDownList4.SelectedItem);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: what is the exception?

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to add the [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) but it's [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.value(v=vs.110).aspx) (or text):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleId", DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Value);
```

or via [`ListControl.SelectedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleId", DropDownList4.SelectedValue);
```

little nitpick: rename your controls to somewhat more meaningful, in this case `DdlRoleId`.

Answer (score 1):

You must rwite : `Email=@Email,` instead of `@Email=Email,` and `RoleId=@RoleId` instead of `@RoleId=RoleId` in your query :

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Users set Username=@Username,Password=@Password,Name=@Name,Address=@Address,Phone=@Phone,Email=@Email,RoleId=@RoleId", conn);
```